# SQL Server Event Notifications & Service Broker - minimum req'd for multiple servers?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to send SQL Server Event Notifications to a separate server using service broker.  I've built an endpoint on each server, a queue on each server, working on Dialogs and Contracts and activation... but do I need any of that?

`CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION` says it can send the notification XML to a "target service" - so could I just create a contract on the "sending" server that points to a queue on a "receiving server", and use activation there?

Or do I need to have it send to a local queue and then forward on to the receiving server's queue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can target the remote service, but you have to have the ROUTEs defined for bidirectional communication so that you get the Acknowledgement message back.  I once had a script for creating a centralized processing server for all Event Notifications, and the other servers targeted it's service.  If I can find it I'll post it on my blog and update this with a link.

Comment: Crap! I forgot I had this open, Jonathon.  I've got it working like a champ and have a presentation on it In google docs and everything. It's fantastic, just a matter at this point of getting some more SSMS/SSRS reports running for it. 

http://thebakingdba.blogspot.com/2012/10/master-of-all-i-survey-using-event.html
Thanks for the initial suggestion - it's been awesome!